# Run Through Data

Tags: excel

[image: Data]I have data about 5 dogs, i.e. their weight, age, height and how much food they eat etc. on another sheet, CostSheet, I have columns that take in this data and calculates the cost based on the information of each dog.

[image]
This is the calculation result for one dog, how will I be able to do all 5 dogs without repeating the calculation

The process of changing the parameters on the CostSheet to calculate the cost for each dog is a lot.

I know I have to use a data table, but I am confused as to how I will go about it

Comment: You should read [ask] first. Then, if this is homework, please provide the full details of what you've been asked to do.

Answer (score 0):

Split your Excel sheet's database functionality from its duty to display the result you want to see. If you have a good database you can always display everything easily. Therefore focus on the utility of your database first.

Data are stored in so-called data sets. A dataset contains information about one subject the nature of which is identical for all your subjects. Each of your dogs is one such subject and the information you want to store about each is Name, Age (Birthdate), Weight, Food Type, Food Qty and Food Cost. Each subject should be in one row and each information in a named column.

The Food Cost might be the result of evaluations imported form another table which is similarly structured.

This display that you published, on the other hand, can be extracted from a single dataset using easy formulas. For example, you could have a dropdown listing all your dogs by name and its dataset will be displayed depending upon your selection in the dropdown. Key is the creation of the datasets: Rows with a unique identifier and structured columns with useful information.